# Laravel - Missing argument 2 for UserController::edit()

Tags: php, sql, laravel, arguments, edit

I'm using the framework Laravel.

I have 2 tables (Users and Persons). When I want to edit the user and at the same time the person, I get the error message:

> Missing argument 2 for UserController::edit()

Table Users

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `festival_aid`.`users` (
  `user_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `user_email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `user_password` CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `user_salt` CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `user_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_modified` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `user_deleted` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `user_lastlogin` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `user_locked` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `user_token` VARCHAR(128) NULL,
  `user_confirmed` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `person_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `user_email_UNIQUE` (`user_email` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_users_persons1_idx` (`person_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_persons1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`)
    REFERENCES `festival_aid`.`persons` (`person_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Table Persons

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `festival_aid`.`persons` (
  `person_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `person_firstname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `person_surname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `person_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  `person_modified` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `person_deleted` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`person_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Model Person

```
class Person extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'persons';

    protected $primaryKey = 'person_id';

    public function person()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

The UserController with edit and update

```
public function edit($user_id, $person_id)
{
    $user = User::find($user_id);
    $person = Person::find($person_id);

    return View::make('users.edit')
        ->with('user', $user)
        ->with('person', $person);
}

public function update($user_id, $person_id)
{
    $rules = array(
        'person_firstname' => 'required',
        'person_lastname' => 'required',
        'user_username' => 'required|unique:users',
        'user_email' => 'required|unique:users|email',
    );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        Redirect::to('users/' . $user_id . '/' . $person_id . '/edit')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput(Input::except('user_password'));
    } else {
        $user = User::find($user_id);
        $person = Person::find($person_id);

        $person->person_firstname = Input::get('person_firstname');
        $person->person_lastname = Input::get('person_lastname');
        $user->user_username = Input::get('user_username');
        $user->user_email = Input::get('user_email');

        $user->save();
        $person->save();

        Session::flash('message', 'Successfully updated user!');
        return Redirect::to('users/index');
    }
```

View Edit

```
<legend>Edit {{ $person->person_firstname }}</legend>

{{ HTML::ul($errors->all()) }}

    {{ Form::model($user, $person, array('method' => 'PUT')) }}

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('firstname', 'Firstname') }}
        {{ Form::text('person_firstname', Input::old('firstname'), array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Firstname')) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('surname', 'Surname') }}
        {{ Form::text('person_surname', Input::old('surname'), array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Surname')) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('username', 'Username') }}
        {{ Form::text('user_username', Input::old('username'), array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Username')) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('email', 'Email') }}
        {{ Form::text('user_email', Input::old('email'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('Password') }}
        {{ Form::password('user_password', array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Password')) }}
    </div>

    {{ Form::submit('Edit the User!', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}

    {{ Form::close() }}
```

The Route

```
Route::get('/users/{user_id}/edit', 'UserController@edit');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function declaration specifies two parameters:

```
public function edit($user_id, $person_id)
```

Yet the route only injects one parameter `user_id`.

```
Route::get('/users/{user_id}/edit', 'UserController@edit');
```

It should look like this:

```
Route::get('/users/{user_id}/{person_id}/edit', 'UserController@edit');
```

Or remove `$person_id` from the function declaration.

Comment: Now it gives me: Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException. I think it isn't able to find the route now..

Comment: I also changed return Redirect::to('users/' . $user_id . '/edit') to this return Redirect::to('users/' . $user_id . '/' . $person_id . '/edit') in the update action

Comment: You need to make sure any links to the edit page have the relevant updates, compare the urls and the route defined. Now you know why it is happening you can probably figure it out. Also update the original question with the new data as an edit.

Comment: I gave this ...users/1/1/edit in the browser and it says SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `persons` where `id` = ? limit 1) (Bindings: array ( 0 => '1', ))

Comment: I needed to give  protected $primaryKey = 'person_id'; in the Person model. Now i get Undefined variable: person

Comment: Undefined variable: person => this is solved when I change            ->with('user', $user, 'person', $person); in the edit action to                                    ->with('user', $user)                                                 ->with('person', $person);

Comment: @Gilko, that sounds about right you could also do `->with(array('user' => $user, 'person' => $person))`