# Missing argument 2 error using db:seed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I received a project from a colleague and it is writing in Laravel which I don't have any experience in. Now with a tutorial I was able to make a database and tables plus some data however when using `php artisian db:seed` I received the same error twice telling me I am missing argument 2 for `Illuminate\databas\eloquent\model:setAttribute()` and I cannot find my fault which is why I decided to ask here and also because I am quite a noob.

**Ticket table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ticket` (
  `idTickets` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `reference` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mail` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `content` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Yes ticket table is longer and has some a primary key, just showing my table just in case.

**Migration code:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTicketsTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('ticket', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
                        $table->string('reference');
                        $table->string('subject');
                        $table->string('name');
                        $table->string('mail');
                        $table->longtext('content');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('ticket');
    }

}
```

**User data:**

```
<?php

// Composer: "fzaninotto/faker": "v1.3.0"DB::table('users')->truncate();
use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class SeedTicketsTableTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('ticket')->truncate();

        $tickets = [
            [
                            `reference`   => 'randomcode1',
                            `subject`   => 'test',
                            `name`      => 'testor',
                            `mail`      => 'testor@mail.nl',
                            `content`   => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'

            ]
        ];

        foreach($tickets as $ticket){
            Ticket::create($ticket);
        }

        foreach(range(1, 10) as $index)
        {
            SeedTicketsTable::create([

            ]);
        }
    }

}
```

I also added the following line into `databaseseeder.php` = `$this->call('SeedTicketsTableTableSeeder');`

Am I missing some code or is this just a simple typo? Thanks in advance for helping. I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731473/missing-argument-2-for-usercontrolleredit-laravel) related question but that did not seem to help much.

*EDIT*

Added ' by content however I still recieved said error.

Comment: Why does your create table query shows a key as "idTickets" and your migration shows a 'id' key?

Comment: I think we need to see your Ticket model. And if you could put up the full error, that'd be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo. Missing ' on line 'content'.

```
use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class SeedTicketsTableTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('ticket')->truncate();

        $tickets = [
            [
                            `reference`   => 'randomcode1',
                            `subject`   => 'test',
                            `name`      => 'testor',
                            `mail`      => 'testor@mail.nl',
                            `content`   => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'

            ]
        ];

        foreach($tickets as $ticket){
            Ticket::create($ticket);
        }

        foreach(range(1, 10) as $index)
        {
            SeedTicketsTable::create([

            ]);
        }
    }

}
```